# Getting from AJAX - Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

> Fatal error:  ob_get_clean() [<a href='ref.outcontrol'>ref.outcontrol</a>]: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in /home/ambient/public_html/staging/app/Tygh/Ajax.php on line 135

Also another error I'm seeing but not sure if related:

> Oops, something went wrong (SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0). Please try again.

I think the JS is question is:

```
function fireCheckoutAC() {
    $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email'), {
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            'email': checkoutEmail,
            'firstname': checkoutFirstName,
            'lastname': checkoutLastName
        },
        caching: true
    });
}
```

Comment: The first error means the issue is in your PHP code, not JS. The second error means that the AJAX request is returning either HTML or XML, not JSON, most likely because it's returning a generic error page instead of the data you're expecting.

Comment: Ahh ok, its weird as works on another server fine just not the other one... think might be magic_quotes or something?

Comment: No idea. All depends on what's happening on line 135 of ajax.php :)

Comment: Lets have a quick look :) give me a moment.

Comment: $text = ($this->_request_type != self::REQUEST_COMET) ? ob_get_clean() : ''; - i did see a PHP Fatel about ob_get_clean actually which is prob the issue with it all. Its a core file so shouldnt be happening so maybe its something on php settings maybe? thanks for your help btw

Comment: It would be easier to check the exact response in the network tab of the console. Hopefully within the HTML will be the actual error message and description

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111802/discussion-between-james-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: I enabled display errors, was a few warnings but the one that i think is the issue is this one: Fatal error: ob_get_clean() [<a href='ref.outcontrol'>ref.outcontrol</a>]: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in /home/ambient/public_html/staging/app/Tygh/Ajax.php on line 135